# Opening .gsheet using colab's drive auto login

Tags: google-sheets, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to open .gsheet files from my personal drive in colab **using the "auto login feature"** to google drive from the colab fileviewer? I am guessing that some sort of conversion is needed, since I am not able to download .gsheet files manually from colab either (.csv work fine)?

```
with open('drive/My Drive/myTable.gsheet') as f:
```

throws *OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: 'drive/My Drive/myTable.gsheet'*